# Typo3 FE login programatically

Tags: authentication, service, typo3, typo3-10.x

In Typo3 post v10 onwards, how can I log in an FE user programmatically with just a user Id number, using the new authentication services and without having to render a form to submit?

I have a custom Typo3 v10 plugin that authenticates users and has worked fine in Typo3 v9 and v10. After checking credentials, I use the following:

```
$userToLogin = 123; //known user id.

$feUser = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user;
unset($feUser->user);
$feUser->createUserSession($userToLogin);
$feUser->loginSessionStarted = TRUE;
$feUser->user = $feUser->fetchUserSession();
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->loginUser = 1;
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->initUserGroups(); 

//reload the page so that restricted subpages appear in menus
$this->redirectToUri($this->linkThisPage);
```

I need to upgrade to V11 and thus to use the authentication service process instead, as $GLOBALS['TSFE']->loginUser is removed in Typo3 v11.

I get it from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60780326/typo3-custom-fe-login-without-form) that this involves setting up a custom service, which is registered in the plugin localConf.php file. The issue is about how to trigger the login process? The example linked above resorts to rendering a mostly hidden form with a "Confirm" submit button that the user must press to trigger the login process. This may work, but looks bad, as the user has already authenticated elsewhere.

Does anyone know how can I trigger the authentication process programatically in a controller, without requiring the form submission? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Authentication Service login is triggered when Typo3 finds the request parameter with a `logintype=login` then your authentication service can do what it needs to do

Comment: Thanks for your reply Wolffc. I can see a way to make this work now.
1. feed the discovered userId into a temporary record with a single use hashkey, 
2. call a page reload using the logintype=login as you suggest,  plus the hashkey
3. in the custom authentication service class getUser function, pick up the hashkey and retrieve the userId.

This should work, but its so much more complicated than the old way of doing it that I can't help thinking there ought to be a direct way to access the process through the API.

Comment: well your Authentication service could also "discover" the userid. depending on the information you give your discovery right know.

we for example allow certian well-known-service a login via username packed in a signed JWT so the login url looks a bit like this: `&logintype=login&jwt=<jwt>` the token is then "invalidated" buy adding the token to a database table of used tokens. and the signature enshures only known services can create them. the table holds the expire date of token. so we can remove old token if they are invalid

Comment: Thanks Wolff, I'll look into JWTs, I'd not heard of them before :-)   I tried my original idea with a hashkey/temp record and it works, if inelegantly.